# Issue mod_rewrite. I need to pass parameters like in REST. Something works wrong

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Issue mod_rewrite. I need to pass parameters like in REST, but when I use this, index.php cannot access their scripts correctly.

Here is the code I use in .htaccess:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|js|video|php)/ ##not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!css|js|video|php)([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|js|video|php)/ #not a directory
RewriteRule ^(?!css|js|video|php)([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&ref=$2 [L]
```

All works when I access `localhost/cocacola` but when I try to access to `localhost/cocacola/someone` whole page scripts doesn't work, images and videos located in `/img` `/video` neither.

They try to access form cocacola directory. Here a link reference: `http://localhost/cocacola/js/jQueryMobile.js`

All this script and videos are in `/js` `/css` `/app` `/video` `/img`.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` to fix this.